# Cannot authenticate a domain user with SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, active-directory

I'm new to setting up Domains so I might be missing something simple here...

I've installed SQL Server 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box and I have another WS2008 R2 box acting as the domain controller.

I've joined the SQL server to the domain and it seems to be behaving itself fine.  I can ping the DC by name and IP address.

I created a domain user 'SPSQLAdmin' that I want to use for database access with SharePoint but I can't seem to log on to SQL with this user.

SQL complains, saying that the user belongs to an untrusted domain.

I've configured the DC to delegate control for any service to the SQL Server but it doesn't improve the situation.

What should I try next?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the SQL box an actual member of the DC's domain and not an isolated workgroup? Also check the surface area configuration in SQL.

Comment: Yes, the computer is part of the domain.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Surface Area Configuration.  How should I check for this?

Comment: No more SAC in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by opening SQL Server Management Studio, connecting to the instance with the SA user or the Windows user that installed SQL, going to Security -> Logins, right click on Logins -> New Login.

Or run this query from a properly credentialed SQL user.

```
USE [master]
GO

/* Create the user in the SQL instance itself with a simple query. */
CREATE LOGIN [YOURDOMAIN\SPSQLAdmin] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
/* And you may want to give them a decent role.  */
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [YOURDOMAIN\SPSQLAdmin]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually add the Domain login within SQL Server?  Simply adding the server to the domain is not enough, you need to add the login to SQL Server using SQL Server Managment Studio to indicate that it is allowed to connect to the server.

Comment: I get an error when attempting to add a login for the domain user that says the user cannot be found.  Sorry I can't give you the exact message as I'm not at the server but it won't let me add a login even though I can do a search for the user from the login dialog and find them in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Pinging by name and IP doesn't mean that you are successfully joined to the domain. Are you able to log on to the server where SQL Server is hosted with the domain admin account? Do you see any errors in the System event log on the server where SQL Server is installed corresponding to issues talking to the DC?

Comment: I added the server to the Domain through the Computer properties and I'm able to log on with the user I'm wanting to add to a SQL login for.